# How to create a JS object with the default prototype from an object without a prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

**Background:** The module [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) is for example able to parse `key=value&hello=universe` to an object `{key: 'value', hello: 'universe'}`. However, the module author has decided that the returned object does not have a prototype. In other words, this "bastard" object is created by `Object.create(null)`.

**Problem:** It would be convenient to use `parsed.hasOwnProperty('hello')` but that is not possible without the default object prototype. Of course, one could `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(parsed, 'hello')` but I think we can all agree that such an expression is kill-immediately-after-birth ugly.

**Question:** How to nicely convert the prototypeless object to have a default object prototype and methods such as `hasOwnProperty`? Additionally, can this be done without using [the feared](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) `__proto__` or `setPrototypeOf`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It would be convenient to use `parsed.hasOwnProperty('hello')` but that is not possible without the default object prototype

The whole point of creating such a "bastard object" is that you cannot do that - what if someone sent a query string `?hasOwnProperty=oops` to your server?

> How to nicely convert the prototypeless object to have a default object prototype and methods such as `hasOwnProperty`?

**Don't.** You should either use the long form with `call`, or just go for the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) which does exactly what you need:

```
'hello' in parsed
```

In an ES6 environment, you might also want to convert the object to a proper [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and use it `has` method.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend changing the prototype of a third party package, it may be frozen and prone to runtime errors. I'd either use the built-in `in` operator as @Bergi suggested or the ES6 Reflect API.

```js
const _ = console.info

const parsed = (
  { __proto__: null
  , foo: 'fu'
  , bar: 'bra'
  }
)

_('foo' in parsed) // true

_('fu' in parsed) // false


/** ES6 (fully supported in current browsers) */

_(Reflect.has(parsed, 'foo')) // true

_(Reflect.has(parsed, 'fu')) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I've ever done this before, but here's one way to do it

```js
let bastard = Object.create(null);
bastard.father = 'vader';

let adopted = Object.assign({}, bastard);
console.log(adopted.hasOwnProperty('father')); // => true
```

Comment: Dude, you used the Force! Excellent, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @AkseliPalén you should read Bergi's post and consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: Your answer was exactly what my question was looking for. The query string provided only an example and I did not meant it to limit the context. Unfortunately, in that example context, your answer has downsides. I am sorry you received downvotes due to this. Nevertheless, I changed Bergi's answer to be the new correct one, as it provides valuable insight.

Comment: @AkseliPalén no problem. Bergi is highly knowledgeable; I've always had good success following his/her advice.

Answer (score 0):

`setPrototypeOf()` is nothing to be feared of, yet without it you might do as follows;

```js
var o1 = Object.create(null),
    o2;
o1.test = "42";
o2 = Object.assign({},o1);
console.log(o2.test);
console.log(o2.constructor.prototype);
```